# Getting the pid from application process launched from open command on macOS

Tags: macos, command-line, java, process

From within a Java application on macOS, I use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -Wn filename")` to launch a file with its Default application, lets call it the Viewing application (for example AdobeReader for pdf). That works fine.

My issue arises, when I want to close the viewing application (for example AdobeReader).

The problem is, that the `open` command itself is launched as a child process of the java application, but the open command launches the viewing application not as a child process, but as child of `launchd(1)`. As a result, when I destroy the process from the Java application, only the open process is killed, but not the viewing application.

So far I could not manage to get a PID of the viewing application process to be able to kill it. With a `ps` I can only find it, when I have the application name, but that is exactly what I do not have, since I want to let the os decide about the viewing application.

Does anybody have an idea how I could

- get the pid of the application that is launched from the `open` command, without knowing the applications Name or UTI(remember, `open` is not the parent process of the viewing application)?

or

- make the launched application a child of the `open` process, so I can kill it by killing the `open` process?

or

- any other possible solution?

Your ideas are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution by getting the pid from the `lsof` command, since I know the filename:

`lsof -t filename`

Having the pid, I can kill the process, means the Viewing Application:

`kill $(lsof -t filename)`

The full solution looks like this:

```
String killCommand = "kill $(lsof -t " + filename+ ")";
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c", killCommand);
builder.start();
```

Not very pretty, but it does the job.

Comment: Hmmmm, I might have to go with this approach.